# How do I change the color of these svg icons of the selected tab?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, radix

I'm wondering how I can most efficiently change the color of the icon of the selected tab.

```
  const [trainColor, setTrainColor] = React.useState('')
  const [busColor, setBusColor] = React.useState('')

  return (
    <StyledSectionContainer>
      <InnerContainer>
        <Tabs.Root defaultValue="tab1">
          <StyledTabsList aria-label="tabs example">
            <StyledTabsTrigger value="tab2">
              <Train
                color={trainColor}
                onClick={() => setTrainColor(theme.color.orange)}
              />
            </StyledTabsTrigger>
            <StyledTabsTrigger value="tab3">
              <Bus
                color={busColor}
                onClick={() => setBusColor(theme.color.orange)}
              />
            </StyledTabsTrigger>  
          </StyledTabsList>
```

Comment: please share `Bus` and `Train` components

Comment: Bus and Train are svg icons from Radix and I'm using them as components.

Answer (score 0):

Radix icons use `currentColor` so, try wrapping you icons with a `div` that provides the color:

```
<div style={{ color: trainColor}}><Train onClick={...} /></div>
```